# Why is Unity (P&P) loading very slow in Windows XP 64 bit SP2?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, unity-container, ants

I've created a new Windows Forms .NET v3.5 solution and added Patterns and Practices **Unity** references with the following command using **Package Manager Console** on visual studio:

> [Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/2.1.505.2)

To simplify, the little app doesn't do anything but trying to instantiate a **UnityContainer** in its loading method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    new UnityContainer();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Winforms Unity initialization took {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed));
    this.Close();
}
```

On Windows 7 it runs quickly, the process exits in less than a second.
The stopwatch log shows less than a millisecond to instantiate Unity.

In **Windows XP 64 bit with SP2** I experience a time of **30 seconds** until this little app quits, but the debug log **still shows that instantiating Unity took less than a millisecond**.

So I thought that maybe the long time has something to do to with the JIT compiler producing native code from Unity's IL code:

I've used **ANTS Performance Profiler** in order to determine which methods are taking too long to execute and saw that the Form1_Load method takes in total 32 seconds,

which contain a JIT overhead of about 30 seconds, which contains a "Waiting for synchronization" of 30 seconds.

Hovering over it shows a tooltip that says:

> This node shows that the executing thread was blocked for a period of
>   time. For example, the thread may have been sleeping, or waiting for
>   access to a shared resource.

I guess this means that loading/JITing Unity takes too long on Windows XP.
I also tried to use NGEN to create a native image of the little app, but things were the same as without using a native image.

Someone knows whats taking so long for Unity to load in XP ?

The DLLs are three:

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll 30 KB
>
> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll 85 KB
>
> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll 122 KB

And they are in release, x86 (that's how I got them from Package Manager)

Comment: Just curious if when you comment out the line `new UnityContainer();` if the app still takes about 30 seconds to load?

Comment: No, It will take less than a second

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a specific Unity problem. What if you replace unity with a different container, say Autofac, and call `new ContainerBuilder()` instead. What will happen than?

Comment: That what we check in that moment

Comment: I try with new SimpleInjector.Container(); and it works fine (less than a second

Comment: It is rather strange that you initialize the container in load event of the form instead of Program.cs. Load event is executed by the main UI thread, which can create overheads when your initialization is slow, so you should avoid that.